# Question on Inactivate with Hold and HoldForm

Tags: evaluation, hold

I am a little bit puzzled by the following, for me inconsistent, behaviour of `Inactivate`.

```
expr=HoldForm[f[a,b]];
Inactivate[expr] // InputForm
(* HoldForm[f[a, b]] *)
```

Nothing has happened. The documentation states, a little bit vague: `Hold` maintains expressions in unevaluated form, and all parts are inactive. With respect to the second statement, observe that the parts inside `Hold` are not wrapped in `Inactive`.

```
expr={HoldForm[f[a,b]]};
Inactivate[expr] // InputForm
(* {HoldForm[f[a, b]]} *)
```

This is as above. However:

```
Inactivate /@ expr // InputForm
(* {HoldForm[Inactive[f][a, b]]} *)
```

Mathematica has to evaluate `{Inactivate[HoldForm[f[a,b]]]}`, for which, according to the first example, I would have expected `{HoldForm[f[a,b]]}`. However, in this situation the heads have been inactivated.

Is there any documentation on this phemomenon? More precisely: under what conditions are the heads in an held expression explicitely inactivated and when not?

Comment: How very odd. `Inactivate[Hold[f[a, b]]]` works as expected, but the indirect approach you demonstrate does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Inactivate` is `HoldFirst`. So, it applies `Inactive` where it can to the unevaluated argument, and then returns the argument. In your example, expr (unevaluated) has no `Head` to inactivate, so `Inactivate[expr]` returns expr, which then evaluates to `HoldForm[f[a,b]]`.

Comment: Further evidence in favor of this answer: `expr = HoldForm[f[a, b]];
Inactivate[Evaluate@expr] // InputForm`

Comment: That is a simple explanation! I thought it had something to do with Hold or HoldForm; that it was the HoldFirst property of Inactivate did not turn up with me. Thanks!

Comment: Is Inactivate precisely the same as HoldFirst in all circumstances? I'm asking because I have many notebooks with delicate (and torturous) control of evaluation for metaprogramming, and I am considering diving into Inactivate to simplify them.